# Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected error with `redirect` tag

Tags: redirect

I have this in a template:

```
{% import "_helpers/macros" as macros %}
{% set redirectUrl = macros.testRelatedReview(entry) %}
{% redirect redirectUrl 301 %}
```

The macro returns an entry URL.

But the page returns an error:

> Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected

If I change it to `{% redirect 'actual_value_of_redirectUrl' 301 %}`, it redirects OK.

How do I get it to work with the dynamic variable though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new line detected` should give you an idea of what to look for - your macro file may have some line breaks between code blocks, and it's writing them to the page before hitting your redirect tag. Try wrapping it all in `{% spaceless %}` tags, and see if that helps?

Comment: Here's some info on whitespace control in Twig: https://symfony.com/blog/better-white-space-control-in-twig-templates and https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#templates-whitespace-control

Comment: Yep, that did it! Thanks :)